# What is the process of pre-linking and How does dynamic loader resolve these?

Tags: c, linux, loader

I came across a problem where _dl_resolve_conflicts was crashing. After a bit of search found it linked error while resolving pre-linked elfs. Can anyone throw some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance that some combination of object files will be referenced by a program, then pre-linking will fix up any references between that set of object files. The linker will still need to fix up references between your program and the object files.

Comment: Thanks , then does that mean that relative addresses will be assigned during pre-linking. And when the process loads during start-up would ld.so again relocate the addresses even after pre-linking?

Comment: @samairtimer - yes, the addresses are still relative, but the symbol table based linkages for the public names in modules accessed as external names in other modules have been replaced with relative offset references, and generally the pre-linked object modules effectively become a single object module.